# Pair-wise multiplication of two integer arrays. If they are of different lengths, the shorter one needs to wrap around

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, integer, multiplication

I have two integer arrays.

```
A[] = {3,4,5,6}
B[] = {1,2}
```

How can we multiply these two arrays in order to get a product of `3456*12` using long multiplication?

Comment: Is there any reason you have to do that using arrays? if not, you can consider using BigInteger.

Answer (score 0):

Very crude example in Python.

```
a = [3,4,5,6]
b = [1,2]
result = []                        
for i in range(0, len(a)):
     result.append(a[i % len(a)]*b[i % len(b)])

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java

```
 public static int mul(int[] a, int []b) {
      int res=0, i, j, mcol, mrow;
      for (mcol=1, i=a.length-1 ; i>=0 ; i--, mcol*=10) {
            for (mrow=1, j=b.length-1 ; j>=0 ; j--, mrow*=10) {
                 res += a[i] * b[j] * mcol * mrow;
            }
      }
      return res;
 }
```

Principle is the same as school multiplication

```
3 4 5 6
x   1 2

=          2x6 + 2x5x10 + 2x4x100 +2x3x1000
   + 10 x (1x6 + 1x5x10 + 1x4x100 +1x3x1000)
```

Starting from `6`, multiply by `2`, then `2 x 5` in 2<sup>nd</sup> position, so you have to `*10` it, and add it to the result, and so on...

For the next digit, `1`, do the same operation, but multiply each time this result again by `10` since `1` is the next digit in the lower row.

---

You can also consider the multiplication from the left side of the arrays.

```
          [ (((0x10 + 1x3)x10 + 1x4)x10 + 1x5)x10 + 1x6 ]
   x10 +  [ (((0x10 + 2x3)x10 + 2x4)x10 + 2x5)x10 + 2x6 ]
```

the function is slightly different

```
 public static int mul(int[] a, int []b) {
      int res=0, resrow, i, j;
      for (i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++) {
            for (resrow=j=0 ; j<b.length ; j++) {
                 resrow = resrow * 10 + a[i] * b[j];
            }
            res = res * 10 + resrow;
      }
      return res;
 }
```

---

Call like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      int a[] = {3,4,5,6};
      int b[] = {1,2};
      int r = mul(a,b);
      out.println(r);
 }
```